# Run time error 424 when using autofilter

Tags: vba, excel

I believe that I have a scope issue because my variable is defined in another module. The error occurs with `WholeSheetRange`. I tried defining it as a global variable but then get an object not set error 91. I then tried to define a new range locally within my routine and then my autofilter did not work. No records were ever found.

Here is my code:

```
Sub date_entered_exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    datevar = inv_list.date_entered
    Dim Rng As Range
    'Dim date_entered As Date
    'date_entered = "13/07/2017"
    'date_entered = Format(inv_list.date_entered, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    If Not IsDate(datevar) Then
        MsgBox "Input must be a date in the format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'"
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set Rng = Range("A:A").Find(datevar)
        Debug.Print datevar
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Input a date within the range"
    Else
        WholeSheetRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=datevar"
    End If

End Sub
```

Here is my code where `WholeSheetRange` is defined:

```
'Declariations to select entire worksheet range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim BigLastRow, LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell, WholeSheetRange As Range 'WholeSheetRange

Set sht = Worksheets("Unfiltered_Flight_Schedule")
Set StartCell = Range("A2")

'turn on autofilter and clear filter if there is one
If Not ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
Else
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If

BigLastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
Set WholeSheetRange = Range("A1:M" & BigLastRow)
```

This code occurs before the date check and is then used in the following way:

```
If stn_DEN.Value = True Then
    WholeSheetRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=DEN"
ElseIf stn_SFO.Value = True Then
    WholeSheetRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=SFO"
End If
```

Comment: okay firstly, if you want to use the variable across the VBA project it needs to be `Public WholeSheetRange As Range`

Comment: Further to that, if you get an error about "set", that mean you literally need to "set" the variable ready for use so something like `set WholeSheetRange = Range("A:B")` or whatever

Comment: I did `Public WholeSheetRange As Range` and have `Set WholeSheetRange = Range("A1:M" & BigLastRow)` but it's still producing an object error 91 object variable or block variable not set and points to `WholeSheetRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=datevar" 'changed from date_variable`

Comment: try to set the variable after below `Else` statement

Comment: Try specifying a sheet when you define `WholeSheetRange`. Even if it doesn't solve your problem, it's good practice. Also, don't think `datevar` should be in quotes as it's a VBA variable.

Comment: I tried moving the statement below the else, which didn't help. I also changed to specify a sheet. and finally tried playing with the quotes. All still result in at type 91 error `Else
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    BigLastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    Set WholeSheetRange = sht.Range("A1:M" & BigLastRow)
End If`

Comment: `Public WholeSheetRange As Range` needs to be at the top of a module, not inside a Sub/Function

Comment: It's at the very top of the module